# Is this the only opening that allows one side to end up with three knights?

Tags: opening, knights, queens-gambit-declined

In Queen's Gambit Declined, Albin counter-gambit, Lasker trap, black ended up with three knights, which should be rare. Here white should not capture the additional knight in the next move (8. Rxg1 Bg4+ and black is winning). Are there any other openings that one side ends up with three or more knights?

```
[FEN ""]
1. d4 d5 2. c4 e5 3. dxe5 d4 4. e3 Bb4 5. Bd2 dxe3 6. Bxb4 exf2 7. Ke2 fxg1=N
```

Answer (score 3):

As @JossieCalderon pointed out, any opening could end up with three knights for one side. This would always require a knight promotion of some sort. Usually, knight promotions occur to

1. Give check to the opponent immediately to move the king to another square or to save a tempo.
2. Avoid a knight fork from the opponent, or give one of your own
3. Avoid stalemate
4. Give checkmate

I think, however, that you are also asking if there is another opening where knight promotion occurs *in the opening phase of the game*. The answer is  most likely "***no***".

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, any opening can allow you to end up with three knights, provided that you promote enough pawns.

Comment: I think that the OP is asking if there is another *known* line in which one side has three knights.